# What's the default Ack mode for spring cloud stream kafka?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Currently I'm using SCS with SB2.0. Just would like to know what is the default ack mode ?

Comment: what is sb2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

The container commits the offset after every record `AckMode.RECORD`.

Comment: With `AckMode.RECORD`, If an exception is thrown, will the offset be committed in

Comment: This question is incomplete. But don’t ask new questions in comments anyway.

Comment: Is it still relevant answer ?

in spring kafka 2.9.7 I see in 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties#setAckMode

Params:
ackMode – the ContainerProperties.AckMode; default BATCH.

Comment: This question was about `spring-cloud-stream` which overrides the default to RECORD by default. Spring for Apache Kafka itself indeed defaults to BATCH.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of SCS](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka) state

> **ackMode**
> Specify the container ack mode. This is based on the AckMode enumeration defined in Spring Kafka. If ackEachRecord property is set to true and consumer is not in batch mode, then this will use the ack mode of RECORD, otherwise, use the provided ack mode using this property.

So it doesn't really help for when `ackEachRecord` is set to `false` (which is the default)

While the [documentation of spring-kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/) state

> The default AckMode is BATCH

So I get from it that it's using the `BATCH` ackMode.